# scala nsc IMain bind() speed and memory issues

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, bind

We are using tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain's bind() and interpret() method to execute scala scripts on a server. This is on on scala 2.9.1 and Java 7u2.

After repeatedly using the same IMain instance, the bind() methods suddenly starts to take very long time (5-6 seconds and even longer). I have tried close() reset() but nothing helps. Weird thing is that the sudden slowness occurs after several uses.

[image]

Code snippet (that is executed over and over again):

```
main.bind("status", status)
try {
    main.interpret(prepare(restriction, input))
} catch {
    case e: Exception =>
        status.setCode("ERR6")
        status.setSummary("Error Interpreting Restriction")
        status.setType(MetaFileElements.ERROR_VALUE)
        status.setValue("Restriction: \"" + restriction + "\", Input: \"" + input + "\"")
}
```

Another Issue is evetually the process crashes with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1061)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.Exceptional$.unwrap(Exceptional.scala:140)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$handleException$1$1.apply(IMain.scala:821)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$handleException$1$1.apply(IMain.scala:818)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anonfun$withoutBindingLastException$2.apply(IMain.scala:228)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:88)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.withoutBindingLastException(IMain.scala:226)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.handleException$1(IMain.scala:818)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:838)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:471)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:503)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:468)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.bind(IMain.scala:525)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.bind(IMain.scala:544)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.bind(IMain.scala:545)
    at com.nomura.fi.spg.kozo.meta.client.helper.RestrictionsHelper$.execute(RestrictionsHelper.scala:22)
```

Comment: Use a profiler, or at least `jstack`, to find out what's happening during that time. The JVM isn't a black box.

Comment: So I ran the process by jvisualvm. Once the slowness occurs the top 3 methods taking longest times are: java.net.SocketInputStream.read(...), java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(...) and java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(...). 64%, 21% and 12% of the time spent there.

Comment: `java.net.SocketInputStream.read(...)` is blocking on socket IO. You might want to use `jstack` first (run repeatedly when it's slow) to figure out what's happening on the relevant thread.

Comment: After stripping off all the other components of the code. The profiler reports following as the hot spots: scala.tools.nsc.interepreter.IMain.bind() 39.2% scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret() 24.5%. Further drill down indicates most of the time spent inside ReadEvalPrint.compile() and Request.compile() methods taking most of the time.

Comment: I have had similar problems. Occasionally I would even get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space. I found using -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m helped. But I would like to find a more efficient way of resolving this myself.